# Find min cost to carry load

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I have `m` trucks to carry load, a given truck is available only on mentioned days from `Left[i] to Right[i]`, the truck capacity is represented as `Capacity[i]` and charges some amount represented as `Cost[i]`

So every truck has 4 parameters, day numbers represented as `Left[i] to Right[i] with Capacity[i] and Cost[i]`

For given `n` days as input and I need to carry a load of capacity `k` on each day, find the minimum cost to transport the load using the trucks.

**Example:**

```
n = 5 days
k = 7 capacity per day
trucks = [[1,3,5,2], [1,4,5,3], [2,5,10,1]], each item in the array represents Left, Right, Capacity and Cost
```

**Answer:**

```
44
```

**Explanation:**

```
for trucks[0] = [1,3,5,2] , it is available on days 1 to 3, with truck capacity as 5 and charges 2

I have a task to carry a capacity of k=7 for each day, with number of days as n=5

a) Day 1

Day 1, we have trucks[0] and trucks[1] but lowest cost is for trucks[0] as 2 but it has only capactity as 5

So Day 1, transport 5 items using trucks[0] and 2 items using trucks[1], so cost is 5*2 + 2*3 = 16

b) Day 2, we can pick trucks[2]=[2,5,10,1] because left=2 matches with the day we are looking for also it can carry a capacity of 10 load.

Cost for Day 2 is 7*1 = 7

c) Day 3, pick trucks[2]=[2,5,10,1] because 3 falls in range [2,5], cost for Day 3 is 7*1 = 7
d) Day 4, pick trucks[2]=[2,5,10,1] because 4 falls in range [2,5], cost for Day 3 is 7*1 = 7
e) Day 5, pick trucks[2]=[2,5,10,1] because 5 falls in range [2,5], cost for Day 3 is 7*1 = 7

Total cost for all days is = 16+7+7+7+7 = 44
```

**Constraints:**

```
n and m range is 1 to 10^4
Also we always have enough trucks to carry the load for a particular day
```

This is my approach:

```
Use for loop from 1 to number of days
    Loop through all the trucks and select the trucks that can carry load in the required days and put them in PriorityQueue that is sorted by cost in descending order.
    Next using a loop, poll items from queue, and calculate cost for given day.
```

My code has time complexity of `O(n*m*m)`, how to solve this in less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get `O(n*m²)` for yours? I see a `O(n*m*log(m))`

```
n-times O(n*...)
  sort-by-m O(mlog(m))
  iterate-over-m //O(m), irrelevant, dominated by previous
```

Could be brought down to `O(n*m+m*log(m))`

```
sort trucks by cost ascending O(m*log(m))
make a int hauled[n] table initialized to zero
int cost=0
for each truck: O(m*...)
  for i from left to right: O(n)
    if hauled[i] < k:
      cost+=truck cost
      hauled[i]+=truck capacity
return cost
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in O(m log m) time.

First create two sorted lists of trucks:

- a "left list" of trucks ordered by the day they become available; and
- a "right list' of trucks ordered by the day they become unavailable;

Then, create an empty [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) of trucks, ordered by cost.  In each node of the tree, we will record the total capacity of its subtree and the total cost to carry that full capacity for a day.  We will store available trucks in here.

Now, process all the "important" days, which are the days on which any truck becomes available or unavailable, in order.

On each important day:

- determine the number of preceding days, since the last important day, that you had to carry freight.
- If that number is not zero, then do a search in the order statistic tree of available trucks to find most expensive truck that you must use, and the total cost and capacity of all the cheaper trucks.  From the result you can calculate the cost per day in the preceding period to carry the required freight.
- Add all the trucks that become available on the current important day to the tree
- Remove all the trucks that become unavailable on the current important day from the tree.